# Ethereum gas limit using Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, nodejs

I am running a private blockchain using Geth, after upgrading the servers- I had stopped the miner and restarted it after upgrading the specs. Now I am getting all sorts of errors, the main one being not being able to HTTP for unlocking wallets; it is a private network. I have to use --allow-insecure and this issue is recent on the git repo as well. 
And now I am getting

> Error: Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"gas required exceeds allowance(8000000) or always failing transaction"}

Anyone face anything similar or have any pointers to give? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok what happened? All answers were deleted . I needed them

Comment: I deleted my answer because I thought it was confusing you and it wasn't helpful. Will undelete if you need something from there. But I think I'm unable to further help you.

Comment: Thanks, no I will up my gas Limit my point is since  it is a private blockchain I cant  modify the genesis.json. I know it is in deployment phase so I can modify but how to increase it?Thank you in advance

Comment: To change the network block gas limit to XXX you have to launch geth with `--miner.gastarget XXX` and `--miner.gaslimit XXX` in miner nodes. The change is not instantaneous (at most in every block it can change 0.1% approx ) so to reach the desired value you might have to mine a lot of blocks.

Comment: yes But I am running geth in a TMUX session, if I change the limit with geth will that render the previous blocks and transactions invalid? and when adding --miner.gastarget I am getting that geth is running

Comment: and now I am getting   invalid command: "\r.pub"   when running geth

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you if you do not provide any information, like geth version, command line parameters or setup you are running. I've used both geth paramters without issues. In any case if it is related to Ethereum please create a new question.

Comment: how should I use  --miner.gastarget ' 9000000' ? I am running latest version of geth so cant use geth.ipc and on a ubuntu server.  the command is geth --ipcpath "path etc... " --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin --rpcpost 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --miner.gastarget

Comment: I've used `geth --datadir data --dev --rpc --miner.gastarget 20000000 console` to set block gas limit to 20M.

Comment: If I have geth miner running In a tmux session, should I run miner.stop() In its console and use  geth --datadir data --dev --rpc --miner.gastarget 20000000 console  in a new tmux session? would it resume the same blockchain? Thank you a lot

Comment: I use windows so I can't help you there. You will have to ask that to whoever have configured your environment.

Comment: I am the one who did  lol . I meant tmux as a session. how do you do it on windwos? just use miner.stop() in the geht javascript console , run the new command with 20000000 parameter added? thank you

Comment: I execute all commands in a cmd windows, if I require a separate application running then I execute another cmd windows.

Comment: how do you leave the geth miner running? or you just test to mine on a windows PC and no servers?

Comment: You have to add the option `miner.gastarget` to miners instance of geth. I've different configurations: for debugging I've a single geth instance and have scripts to start and stop mining, for production there are dedicated instances to mine and will have it enabled from boot as a systemd service.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the block gas limit in your network has fallen bellow 8M, and your transaction gas is above 8M. Transactions with gas above the network gas limit are not processed until the limit rises.

You can check `gasLimit` of the latest block in your network executing `eth.getBlock('latest')` from geth's console.

Possible options:

- Send transaction with less gas to execute it successfully
- Rise the network gas limit. Pass the option `--miner.gaslimit value` to geth and mine blocks until the limit is reached.

Comment: Hello,But I am mining so I should be having more gas thus be able to "afford" such a transaction

Comment: What is the gas limit in the latest block? Mining is needed to change the gas limit but you can configure it to go down or up.

Comment: it is 8000000 according to eth.getBlock('latest')

Comment: Why/how could I configure it to go down though? Isn't it counterproductive?If it gets to 0 it would be theoretically possible but no one would verifiy- this is the case of MainNet. On my private network should I just use gas price thus cost to 0? Since I am the only miner

Comment: You can configure gas limit to go up/down using the geth command line option in my answer. It indicates how many transactions you can include in a block (minimum per transaction is 21K, contracts require more).

Comment: @test1234 How do you created the transaction that is failing? It seems the gas option is above 8M that is why it is being rejected.

Comment: Yes, the transaction is sending a token. adding --gaslimitvalue to geth isnt working. It use to work before but as you mentioned gas limit for latest is 8000000 and I cant change genesis.json at the risk of having to recreate wallets for users etc...